# Use object in attribute

Tags: polymer

I want to use an attribute of my note object in my html attribute

```
<div id="disco-grid">
  <template repeat="{{note in _notes}}">
    <disco-pad note="{{note.midi}}"></disco-pad>
  </template>
</div>
```

The code

```
"{{note.midi}}"
```

is not evaluated and just returns it as a string, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Make sure that you have specified the note attribute in your element

```
<polymer-element name="disco-pad" attributes="note">
```

If that still doesn't work try creating a stub of your _notes in your javascript file

```
Polymer({
    _notes: {
        midi: 'something'
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue was indeed in the disco-pad element, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear, make sure to mark this answer as the correct one so that future readers can easily find the solution to this problem :)